# How to retrieve all the supervisors upto the CEO?

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image]

Lets say I have this table. **Each employee has a supervisor** except the **CEO** who is the last one.  I am using already built table and I can't modify, so this is what I get from the table.

I would like to build a query which keeps track all the supervisors.

**Example:**
I search for **Steve Smith**

**Output result:**

```
David Brown
  Bob Williams
   Richard Jones
```

---

**Another Example:** I  search for **David Brown**

**Output result:**

```
 Bob Williams
   Richard Jones
```

---

I have not come a cross with this issue before

Comment: Is the order important? or just the results?

Comment: @AfromanMakgalemela the order is important; I wanna keep track up to the CEO. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server and many other DBMSes support [recursive queries](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) that can walk the chain of command in a single SQL statement. This step is typically contained within a common table expression (CTE) that is joined or filtered by the final/outermost `SELECT`.